# LINQ to objects performance

Tags: c#, linq

I am constructing a LINQ query on a DataSet, it will have a .Where condition, .Distinct and .OrderBy. I was thinking of doing this manually at first, at best I can probably manage this in two loops. Which method is faster? Is there anyway to see what LINQ does in the background?

Comment: You'll have to try each way and measure it.

Comment: Don't choose LINQ because it's faster. Mostly it is not, but it's also negligible compared to loops. Choose what you can understand and maintain faster.

Comment: We couldn't say without seeing both the linq and non-linq code samples.  Which is better will depend on the specifics of how you implement them.  Once you *do* implement them, rather than asking us, you should simply [race the horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/) rather than guessing which is faster.

Comment: If performance is your goal, then you should be using an indexed dictionary or multi-map, and querying via that - not using a datatable  and "scan"

Comment: Choose LINQ. Linq is faster and smoother. Place joins that allow caching inside linq. They make the thing faster.

Comment: @dev that is nonsense. LINQ to Objects and a Where is a pretty way of wrapping a loop and predicate, but by definition it can only *add* overhead. Maybe not a lot, but some. It certainly can't magically make a naive "scan" quicker.

Comment: @MarcGravell Joins inside linq to objects do cache. Consider reading more about linq joins before placing such statements.

Comment: @dev the question here is Where, and thank muchly but I am plenty familiar with LINQ

Comment: @MarcGravel Where with AsParallel is faster than any "scan" of yours. Btw where alone itself is that "scan" that you talking about.

Comment: @devhedgehog:  I'm curious where joins come into play when the question doesn't state the use of a second data source and only explicitly states the use of Where, Distinct, and OrderBy.

Comment: @dev yes, I know that Where is a "scan" - that is exactly what I said. We AsParallel: you need to define "faster" here. Do you mean elapsed time based on being able to use all cores? Or do you mean total CPU used? Because AsParallel can *only add* overhead. On a client app, that might be great. On a server app, often not so much - you've added load and swamped the cores. But in both cases, a design change ("use the index") would be far far preferable

Comment: @AustinSalonen DataSet by definition in c# is set of tables. DataTable is one table. :) I thought the op has few tables and on those he might wish to find something or get all unique items by calling distinct. Joins will come handy there.

Comment: @MarcGravell fast to me means the amount of time a computer needs to do certain computations. therefore following that definition there are fast computers and slow onces. makes sense right?. Linq where statement on 1k items with as parallel is faster than simple "scan". Linq on two tables each 1k items with joins if faster than simple "scan" on two tables.

Comment: By faster I meant time-elapsed, I am working with an enormous amount of rows, and having experienced noticeable performance differences in the past with EF vs ADO.NET, I just want to use the fastest method, regardless of quantity of code I need to write.

Comment: Firstly I hope use are not using a ADO.NET dataset, if so you may have bigger problems. There are Indexed LINQ systems about e.g. http://i4o.codeplex.com/ that will create indexes for you while still letting you write clear code that looks like Linq to objects.

Comment: No, ADO.NET was another project, which I coded purely for speed and it wasn't using DataSets, I'll take a look at Indexed LINQ, looks promising.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there anyway to see what LINQ does in the background?

Well, you could look at my [Edulinq implementation](https://code.google.com/p/edulinq/) and the accompanying blog posts to get an *idea* of what's going on in LINQ to Objects. Obviously it's not the real implementation, but it will give you a good enough idea.

I would strongly suggest setting yourself some reasonable performance targets, implementing the code in the simplest possible way (which is almost certainly to use LINQ) and then seeing whether it meets your targets.

There are situations where hand-coding this sort of thing *can* bring significant improvements - but they're relatively rare, and you should only go for that after proving that it's worth it, IMO. LINQ is at least "pretty good" when used properly.

Answer (score 4):

LINQ isn't about *performance*, it's about *productivity*.  Building your own loops may result in a faster program, but unless you *measure* it, you wont know how much faster if at all.

On the other hand, you could probably write a Linq query in a fraction of the time spent writing the loops, and use the rest of that time optimizing the parts of the application that *are* slow and *can* be significantly improved.

Answer (score 2):

Which is faster: *me* looking through a textbook page by page until I find the usages of a word I want, versus me asking *someone else* to look through the same textbook page by page looking for the usages, nudging me every time they do?

If you are concerned about performance, what is usually needed is a *design change to accommodate that* - for example, using the index.